# why pass window pointer in callback function opengl

Tags: c++, glfw

why do we pass GLFWwindow pointer to parameter when we don't use the window pointer variable

example:

```
   coid sizecallb(GLFWwindow* window, int w, int h){
      glViewport(0,0,w,h);

      screeenw = w;
      screeenh = h;
}
```

Comment: Its mainly there so you can extract [User pointer](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_userptr) because glfw is a C library first and C has no lambdas that could capture any user data like you otherwise could in C++.

Comment: You don't use it. Maybe someone else would like to use it. GLFW allows you to create multiple windows. The window pointer identifies the window that was resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done because GLFW is written in C, not C++. Therefore, there's not so much ways to distinguish one window from another. Also, it's not **us** who pass info to callbacks, it's GLFW that executes callbacks from its code. It specifies window handle so that you can choose the window for which this callback is meant to be called. When you have only one window, this argument can be left unused. But when you create multiple windows, and you have all window handles, you can choose a window object with the handle passed in callback and execute a method on only one exact window object.

Note that you can specify different callbacks for different windows.